# The Compose file '.\docker-compose.yml' is invalid because: services.server.ports is invalid: Port ranges don't match in length

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Файл **server.env**, находится на одном уровне с **docker-compose.yml**

- docker-compose.yml

```yml
version: "3"
services:
  server:

    env_file:
      - server.env

    build: server/

    command: python ./server.py

    ports:
      - ${EXTERNAL_PORT}:1234

  client:

    build: client/
    command: python ./client.py

    network_mode: host

    depends_on:
      - server
```

- server.env

```
EXTERNAL_PORT=1234
```

Я также пытался из командной строки запустить (разумеется тогда настройки из *.env не должны учитываться)...

```bsh
docker-compose run -e EXTERNAL_PORT=1234 server python server.py
WARNING: The EXTERNAL_PORT variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
ERROR: The Compose file '.\docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.server.ports is invalid: Port ranges don't match in length
```

вот один из примеров, что нашел

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите в чем ошибка может быть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[env_file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env_file-configuration-option) предназначен для того, чтобы создавать переменные внутри контейнера, т.е. в вашем случае внутри `server` контейнера будет существовать `EXTERNAL_PORT`.

Для того, чтобы это начало работать в `docker-compose.yml` нужно назвать файл [.env](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file) (без слова server) и соответственно исправить `docker-compose.yml`:

```yml
env_file:
  - .env
```

Тогда при вызове `docker-compose up` все будет ок.

Comment: Но это работает только тогда, когда *.env находится там же, где и docker-compose.yml. Если *.env. находится в некотором каталоге, например, server/.env - тогда снова получаю ошибку. Почему ? Кроме того, я видел много примеров compose-файла, где показано, что используется файл  *.env., с некоторым именем.